# Can I use taxonomy field to display in URL using [current-page:query:?] token?

Tags: path-aliases, tokens

[image]How to display header field in URL with query token with Drupal 7?

Working on this site, and I disabled title field for taxonomy terms, instead I put a header in there...didn't know could lead to problems later;(

So now I want the header field "field_header" that substitutes the title to show up in URL for SEO with Pathauto paterns and token.

Tried this [current-page:query:?]:

```
[term:parents]/[current-page:query:field_header]
```

But not working, am I missing something here?

Comment: are you sure about it? is field_header a search field or filter field somewhere in you site?   `current-page:query:?` usually used for "The value of a specific query string field of the current page."

Comment: I added an image to explain;)

Answer (score 0):

According to your image, `field_header` is part of your content type so it's available on **[node:field_header]** token, and all that you need is add it to your content type URL pattern.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good but first of all there is no such thing under token tool...so I added it manually and then I got this error:                                              Default path pattern (applies to all vocabularies with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:field_header].

Comment: @BrunoVincent do you want to use it in your vocabulary URL pattern??? are you sure?

Comment: @BrunoVincent  you want use Vocabulary on  Content type URL pattern or  Custom field in Vocabulary URL Pattern?